TL072 troubleshoot
I've been working on a preamp using the TL072 for a DIY guitar AMP.
I've tried using this design and putting it as a circuit:
https://www.elcircuit.com/2016/09/hifi-audio-preamp-circuit-tl072.html
I connected it to a -12V, +12V and ground power source, I don't get any signal through.
this is how my circuit looks at the moment:

(by the way, I'm using a 12V single powersupply and then a PP1912PA as a power source to make a dual power supply. I just visualised it as this because in tinkercad because negative voltages aren't possible yet in the software)
powersource (12V 10A single power supply on the left)

circuit images:



does anyone maybe know what could be wrong?

Are you certain all your connections are correct, and none of those bare resistor  and capacitor leads are shorted to each other?

@Hearth yeah, all capacitors are places correcty, i know it's pretty hard to see in the perspective that i shot the image.

Although it may not be the cause of no throughput, C6 (a 47uf polarized capacitor) seems to be installed with wrong polarity - that's dangerous.

@SamVandebeek - Hi, (a) Can you add a second, wider-angle (i.e. zoomed-out) photo? Some cables are impossible to trace until we can see both ends and the wire between. (b) The red wire plugged into row (or column, depending on your naming) number 21 seems isolated. What do you think it connects to? Why is it there? (c) What test equipment do you have? Scope? DMM? Anything else? (d) Just out of interest, where did you get the TL072 from? Have you used it before so it is (or at least, was then) confirmed as working? (e) The 2x electrolytics on the lower red bus bar seems wrong. Please explain.

@SamGibson, are these more clear?

@SamVandebeek - TY, those extra photos do help. Some parts are not yet completely clear to me without further careful review, but they might be enough for people with younger eyes :)

@SamGibson, I've now putten it in tinkercad and took a screenshot. Hopefully this is now a bit better. Circuits are always such a mess

C6 is wrong in the 2nd image, the positive lead should be connected to GND and the negative to -12V.

@Gos, thanks for adressing this mistake, i've now fixed this. It didn't have any effect on the output though

Have you verified the power supply voltages on the breadboard? Based on how you drew the Tinkercad, it looks like you might have +12V on both rails.

@DaveTweed , yes, i have use a 12V single power supply and then use a DD1912PA to turn 12V DC to +-12V DC. Tinkercad just doesn't allow negative voltages yet in diagrams.

@SamVandebeek Can you also add a photo of your board?

@EdinFifić I've tried my best taking pictures, but it's always such a mess when working with unpermanent breadboards

@SamVandebeek If everything else is good (multimeter, battery, supply voltages), then another possibility is that those jumper wires either have a high resistance or a break in them, and you won't know it until you check with an ohmmeter. I had come across such very poor quality colored jumpers. Another issue could be poor contacts in your board, combined with poor jumper wires. I had once made a simple circuit and couldn't figure out why I had large voltage drops. Measuring voltages on the wires or on the board contacts, I realized that poor contacts were causing the issue.

@SamVandebeek Sometimes the best option is to build your circuit on one of those pre-drilled universal circuit boards or perf boards, that way you have much better connections and a much better insight into your connections and their quality.

@SamVandebeek - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "áccepting" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either your answer (which can be áccepted after 2024-10-02 @ 15.22 UTC i.e. 48 hrs after the question was asked) or another answer (which can be accepted any time) if you consider it the best one.

Found the problem. The DD1912PA was apparantly faulty so i had to find another way to get a dual powersupply. Now it works!

Thank you for letting us know. As you can see, it is hard to know what is wrong without checking everything, even if we have plenty of knowledge and experience in the field. Just make sure in the future to have a good multimeter (or a decent appropriate tool/instrument for the job in general) so that you can track and eliminate simple problems without wasting too much of your time and energy. I have spent many thousands just in the last 3 years on tools, equipment, instruments and components, and I still have ways to go.

From your image of the board and power supply connections, I see two problems:

The left power supply has the polarities connected wrong, which makes the total supply voltage 0 volts for your op-amp, as the two supplies are cancelling each other out. The negative end of the upper supply needs to connect to the positive end of the lower supply, so that they add up to a total of twice their single voltages.

The right capacitor is oriented incorrectly, you need to turn it around so that its negative side goes to the most negative supply side.


Here is your image edited with these suggestions:


yes, i have use a 12V single power supply and then use a DD1912PA to turn 12V DC to +-12V DC. Tinkercad just doesn't allow negative voltages yet in diagrams.

I've turned around the capacitor but it didn't change the output

Can you add a photo of your setup (add it to your question) so that the wiring from the power supply is visible?

just added it to the original post

@SamVandebeek Have you checked the voltages, starting from the mains supply, coming out of the converter board and on your circuit board itself?

@SamVandebeek Try placing two resistors of 1kΩ resistance, one from the +12V to GND and the other from -12V to GND, and let me know if that made it work.

I've tried what you told but i don't hear much difference. Just a very soft bit of static when i touch one of the poles of the input, but when plug my guitar in the jack and i play something, the speakers aren't vibrating. Between the TL072 and the speaker are TDA2030 amplifier circuits by the way. I'm not able to check the PP1912PA because my multimeter can't handle the current, but the chance something is wrong with that is small because i can get some loud static when touching for example R4.

@SamVandebeek When measuring voltages, a voltmeter's CURRENT capability is unimportant. Do you know how to measure a voltage with a voltmeter or multimeter? If not, let us know multimeter model, and we will tell you how.

I'm just using a cheap old multimeter. The thing is that i put it on the mode 20V DC, but when i put black on ground and red on +12V or -12V. I always get a "-1 error". even when trying to measure the volts of the power supply, when i connect black to -V and red to +V I get the same error. I've looked up online how to use it again because it has been a while but i still can't get it to work.

@SamVandebeek, "...  the speakers aren't vibrating ...". You aren't trying to drive a speaker directly with a TL072 are you? Do you mean an amplifier-speaker combination?

@Transistor , no, after the TL072 is a TDA2030 circuit but these 100% work fine

@SamVandebeek Your multimeter is bad, its battery voltage too low OR the tested voltage is too high. There are many cheap multimeters and you should get one if yours doesn't work. If it's the battery, you should insert a new one. Most of us electronics guys have at least two multimeters so it's easy for us to check another DMM's battery voltage. The symbol on your display is most likely showing an "overvoltage" or out of range, meaning you are trying to measure a voltage above the range you have set it to. Try setting it to the 200V range, you will still have enough resolution of 0.1V.

Thank you so much, i think my multimeter is just a bit outdated. I just ordered a new one and ill see soon if this will work beter (most likely it will)!
